# Removing an Object from a set nullifies its inverse relationship in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mogenerator

I have a ObjectA which has a one-to-many relationship with ObjectB. ObjectB has an inverse one-to-one with ObjectA. It all seems to go well until I realised that calling `[objectA.objectBSet removeAllObjects]` breaks the inverse relationship of ObjectB's instances which where inside the Set. `objectA.objectBSet` is just the `NSMutableOrderedSet` of the objectBs which I (think) I get from the **mogenerator** tool (if that makes any difference).

Is this possible or I am doing something wrong? Can it be that simply removing an object from the set of its parent can influence the value of its inverse relationship automatically from CoreData?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it's supposed to work. If two relationships are inverses, then they must be consistent with each other for every object. If you tell an `ObjectA` to remove all relationships to instances of `ObjectB`, then those `ObjectB` instances will also remove their relationship to that `ObjectA`. That's how inverse relationships work. If the `ObjectB` instances still claimed to be related to the `ObjectA` instance, the inverse relationship would be in an inconsistent state.

If this isn't what you want for some reason, use relationships between `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` that are **not** inverses of each other.

Comment: Thanks! This is consistent with the results I m seeing. Is there a way to disable it through a property or a flag somewhere (apart form breaking the inverse)?

Comment: No, that's how inverses work. If you need different behavior, you need more than one non-inverse relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CoreData will nullify the inverse relationship for you when you remove objects from the Set. Or if you do objectB.objectA = nil it will also remove objectB from objectA's set.